# QGIS Plugin Map Composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I search a plugin or another good way to generate different maps, with the same layout. With this plugin a user should be able to create a map from his data. I set the parameters for the map, so every map should have the same layout, the same position and style for the legend etc.

Is there maybe any plugin with this functions or an other possibilty?

Comment: Maybe, [Print Composer templates](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/composer/).

Answer (score 1):

It's called a "template" and you can create these for your users to load as a map and then put data in it. Open the composer, build your template and save it as one. Done.

Comment: I know the composer and the templates. But I search for a simple way, that the users only load their data and get a final map and can´t change anything in the map, execpt the input, the output, the name. In the mapcomposer they could change the parameters on their own, even if I look them before.

Comment: Then simply tell the users not to change the template, because maps your company turns out should always look the same. And by locking said elements, there at least is another level of security.
Or - maybe a mad idea - you create a svg containing all elements not to be changed, place it in the template and lock it.

Comment: Ok thank you. I hoped that maybe someone has a good plugin for the problem. then I have to continue using the mapcomposer.